# How to implement shape manipulation on a drawing canvas?

Tags: java, mouseevent, shapes

I have a vector (_storedShapes) to store the painted rectangles (_rect). I also plan on adding ellipses. What I am trying to do is add a shape to the spot on the screen that I click and be able to resize it. Here is a website with a demo of what I am trying to do http://code.google.com/p/tangram-canvas/downloads/detail?name=TangramCanvas-1.2.zip.

The only difference from this demo is that I want my shape to expand on all sides from its center as I drag it.

From my code right now, a pre-sized rectangle pops up on the canvas where I click and then when I drag, just follows the cursor on the screen.

```
private class DrawSListener extends MouseAdapter {

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        _preX = (int) (_rect.getX() - e.getX());
        _preY = (int) (_rect.getY() - e.getY());
        DrawingPanel dp = new DrawingPanel();
        _rect = new SketchyRectangle(dp);
        System.out.println("new rec");

    //  if (_rect.contains(e.getPoint())) {
            _rect.setLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
            System.out.println("setLocation");
            repaint();
            System.out.println("paint");
        //} 
    }
}

/**
 * Private class DrawListener is called when the DrawEllipse or DrawRectangle radio buttons are selected. 
 *
 */

private class DrawListener implements MouseMotionListener {

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (_rect.contains(e.getPoint())) {
            _rect.setLocation(_preX, _preY);
            _storedShapes.add(_rect);
            repaint();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep two coordinates in the object (or wherever makes sense): prevDragCoord, shapeCenter.  On mouse click store the coordinate of the event in both members.  On mouse drag, update the rectangle size by adding to it the difference of the current event coordinate minus the coordinate stored in the object.  Set the rectangle's location by setting the difference between the shapeCenter member and the rectangle size divided by 2 (e.g. shapeCenter.x - rect.xLength/2).  Store the current coordinate in the object's coordinate member so it's ready to update on any subsequent calls to your handler.

I'll leave the implementation up to you.  Maybe you can do it with only one variable, or maybe no variables because the event object has some sort of awesome data in it to get this done.  This should be the general idea anyway.